# diplaying images from database in jQuery plugin: Galleriffic

Tags: php, jquery, database, image

I'm using a jQuery plugin- Galleriffic ([link here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f49/tutorial-upload-files-to-database-176804.html))

And I'm also following this  tutorial: [Upload Files To Database](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f49/tutorial-upload-files-to-database-176804.html)

Okay, the images are now in the database but I'm not able to view the images from the database using this:

```
<img src="getpicture.php?fid=1">
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the header to 
`header("Content-Type: image/jpeg")`

For testing call the URL

```
getpicture.php?fid=1
```

and see what happens?

edit: On step 5

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['fid']))
{
// connect to the database
include "connect.php";

// query the server for the picture
$fid = $_GET['fid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE fid = '$fid'";
print $query;
$result  = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
print_r($result);

// define results into variables
$name=mysql_result($result,0,"name");
$size=mysql_result($result,0,"size");
$type=mysql_result($result,0,"type");
$content=mysql_result($result,0,"content");
print "check point 1 => $name, $size, $type, $content";
// give our picture the proper headers...otherwise our page will be confused
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
echo $content;

mysql_close();
}else{
die("No file ID given...");
}

?>
```

Replace with above code and call from the browser and see what its printing?

Comment: I have set the header as you said, and I test the url but nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

on `getpicture.php`

1. get the id of image
2. query database.
3. echo out the image after `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg")`